# Python Function Prototype

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def tempr():
        print("in the function")

.
.
.
.
tempr()
```

This way the python function works, while

```py
tempr()
.
.
.
.
.
def tempr():
    print("in the function")
```

This does not work

> while in c++ we have a prototype declaration to tell the compiler that the function exists.
> what do I do here? Can Python handle such kind of c++ kind of function call statement above the function definition

Comment: No you cannot do this, functions have to be declared before they can be called in Python. A function is no different from a "variable" in python, they are both objects and they both must be defined before they can be referenced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: you have to follow a `top-down` structure in your code, and it's good practice. The way you have set it up is basically resulting in an `undefined` function being called as it has not even been setup in the memory stack (at run-time).

Answer (score 2):

> what do I do here?

Define or import the function before you call it. There's no way around it.

> Can Python handle such kind of c++ kind of function call statement above the function definition

No, Python does not currently have function prototypes. As Iain Shelvington said, functions and variables are objects. (Literally, everything is an object in Python) As you must define a variable before use, same as functions. You could put the function in another file and import it if you don't want to see it...